# Models and its iterates

Tags: set-theory

Let $1\leq n<\omega$ and suppose that $M_n^\#$ exists.  If $\mathscr{M}$ is an iterate of  $M_n^\#$, why cannot happen that $M_n^\#\in \mathscr{M}$?

Comment: This is a normal iteration, I assume? Iterates of sound models share the same reals. But $M_n^\sharp$ is coded by a real, so you would have $M_n^\sharp\in M_n^\sharp$. If you have a stack of trees, the argument is similar, just check the agreement condition.